# Finding a basis of a polynomial vector space of degree at most 3.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have the following subspace of polynomials ( $p(x)$ ) with degrees up to $3$:

$$U = \{ p(x) \ \vert\  p'(0) = p(1) \}$$

So the value of the derivative at $0$ equals the value of the function at $1$. I've shown that this is a subspace, and I've found that the form of such a function is $p(x) = ax^3-ax^2+bx$. But I'm lost when I need to find a basis for this subspace.

Comment: Knowing that every $P\in U$ has the form $p(x)=a(x^3-x^2)+bx$ says precisely that $U$ is _spanned_ by the two polynomials ??? and ???.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your space is equal to$$\{ax^3+bx^2+cx-a-b\mid a,b,c\in\mathbb R\}.\tag1$$A basis of this space will be$$\{x^3-1,x^2-1,x\}.\tag2$$I got this basis by looking at $(1)$ and:

- the first element of $(2)$ is what I get from $(1)$ when I put $a=1$, $b=0$, and $c=0$;
- the second element of $(2)$ is what I get from $(1)$ when I put $a=0$, $b=1$, and $c=0$;
- the third element of $(2)$ is what I get from $(1)$ when I put $a=0$, $b=0$, and $c=1$.

Comment: So if I wrote these polynomials as [1, 0, 0, -1], [0, 1, 0, -1] and [0, 0, 1, 0] would the vector [0, 0, 0, 1] extend the subspace to the vector space of polynomials of degree 3?

Comment: Yes, since it is not a linear combination of the other three.