# Extending a basis of a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let's say I have a subspace of polynomials of the following form:

$$p(x) = ax³ + bx² + cx - a - b.$$

I've found a basis of this subspace: $\{ x^3 - 1, x^2 - 1, x \}$, and now I want to extend this basis to a basis of all polynomials of degree 3 or less.

I believe adding a 1 to my basis would be enough, but that is nothing more than a guess from my part. How do I come to this conclusion legitimately, without any guesswork (in short how do I show my work)?

Comment: You are correct. To show it, take a general cubic, and express it in terms of your $4$ polynomials. $$a(x^3-1)+b(x^2-1)+cx+(d+a+b)(1)=ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$$

Comment: Seems related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3559826/16192

Comment: @gt6989b The fact that both were asked today... suspicious.

Answer (score 1):

One way is following. Try to express each vector in standard basis $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$ 
with this basis of subspace. And if you can not do it then plug it in.

Say we try that with $x^3$: $$x^3 = a(x^3-1)+b(x^2-1)+cx$$ we get $a=1$ and $b=c=0$ clearly imposibile. So $$\{x^3,x^3-1,x^2-1,x\}$$ is a basis of whole space.